# Probability - Calculate chance total score will be over or under a score line

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I am working on a model which predicts the total final score (sum of the scores of both teams) of certain sports matches. I have checked the predictions of the model against the actual scores of matches for the last several years. The error in the predicted total score to the actual toal score is approximately normally distributed with mean $=-0.3$ and standard deviation $= 13$.

Say I have a predicted total score $x$, how can I determine the probability that the actual score will above or below a given score line $y$.

For example, say my model predicts that the total score will be $8$ and the score line is $5.5$, what is the probability that the actual score will be $\le 5$ and  what is the probability that the actual score will be $>5$ (given that the errors in my prediction can be assumed to be normally distributed)?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_set

Comment: Thank you, that has given me an insight but I am still struggling to understand how to calculate the probabilities I'm after. Would a worked example be possible?

Comment: One warning:  Just because you can follow the calculation of a standard deviation doesn't mean the distribution is Gaussian.  Most real world distributions have larger tails than the Gaussian would predict, so the likelihood of a value farther from the mean than 3 sigma (for example) is much larger than 1 in 370.  Closer to the mean things aren't so bad.  One of my favorite remarks goes something like "Physicists think the Gaussian distribution is a mathematical theorem, mathematicians think it is an experimental fact."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, sorry for misunderstanding your point. So, your model predicts $PV=8$ with errors $\epsilon \sim N(-0.3,13)$. Or, this is equivalent to saying that you expect the actual value to be $AV \sim N(8.3,13)$. ($PV=AV+\epsilon$)

Now, to compute the probability that $X\leq 5.5$ (or $x>5.5$) under the hypothesis that your model is correct. This is

$$\mathbb{P}(X\leq 5.5|X \sim N(8.3,13)) \; .$$

I don't know what programming language or other computer program you use, but most math or statistics interpretative languages (Matlab, R, etc...) have the necessary commands inbuilt. So in R, you would use the command

```
pnorm(5.5,8.3,13)
```

which computes the cumulative normal distribution in point $5.5$ for mean and variance as given. For the probability bigger than $5.5$, you take

```
1-pnorm(5.5,8.3,13)
```

If you want the explicit formula for the computation, I can provide that too, but unless you want to make a lot of extra work implenting the functions yourself, I don't think that is really useful.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand fully, does \mu_0 = 8 (i.e. what my model predicts) and \sigma_0 = 5.5 (i.e. the score line) or are \mu_0 and \sigma_0 supposed to be -0.3 and 13 respectively (i.e. the mean and stdv of the prediction errors)

Comment: Well, I took the values of your final example. Why do you change example by the way? I have the impression you are confused about something, but I can't tell what. If you know that your model is a normal distribution, you should already know what to do. Yet, you seem lost? Strange.

Comment: I don't believe I changed the example...? I am a bit confused, I'm happy to admit.

Comment: What are your model values? Is it -0.3 and 13 or is it 8 and 5.5?

Comment: OK, I apologize, I seem to have been reading your post incorrectly. So, your model values are $\mu_0=-0.3$ and $\sigma_0=13$.

Comment: My model will predict that the total score of the game will be some value `x`. The errors in the prediction against the actual total score of the game  are normally distributed with \mu = -0.3 and \signma = 13.

Comment: OK, I see, it's the errors that are normally distributed. I'll adapt my answer.

Comment: Say the model is predicting the outcome of a soccer match between team A and team B. The model gives a prediction of the sum of the scores of A and B. I have tested the model against past games and the mean error in the prediction against the actual score of games is -0.3, with standard deviation 13.

Comment: I adapted the answer, again, sorry for misreading your post. It was actually clearer than I thought. I was the confused one.

Comment: Just one last thing to be certain, is the relationship between Predicted Value (PV), Actual Value (AV) and error ($\epsilon$) as follows: $PV=AV+\epsilon$ or is it $AV=PV+\epsilon$ ? This is also important. Because in the first case, the mean should be $8-(-0.3)$ in the second it should be $8+(-0.3)$.